# Live search in table rows with rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a table which contains rowspans in the the first column. I have a code but when I search it collapse. My table looks something like this: [Table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wg1TxK-DOM83cZxmCdUoFkVqZI5FEf7P/view?usp=sharing).

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function () {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr").each(function (index) {
    if (index !== 0) {

      $row = $(this);

      var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
        $row.hide();
      }
      else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>XY</th>
    <th>ZW</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">321</td>
    <td>242</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>513256</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33131</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4131</td>
    <td>334132</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">51311</td>
    <td>54424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5442</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>511</td>
    <td>544</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: use closest jquery method to hide parent "tr"

Comment: The input tag has no end tag. Remove `</input>`.

Comment: @AyazAlavi now i use: if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {$row.closest('tr').hide();} but nothing change, it still wrong.

Comment: let me write sample code, give me a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at jsfiddle [here][1]

```
 $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
        $("td").closest("tr").hide()
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value) {
        $("td:contains('"+value+"')").closest("tr").show()
    } 
    else {
        $("td").closest("tr").show()
    }
});
```

Updated code that takes rowspan in consideration:
https://jsfiddle.net/nbys6fqm/
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/c6nopaes/

Comment: It still wrong. Try to run the code, for me it is still wrong.

Comment: @AyazAlavi I would like to clarify, When I search for a rowspan line, I would like to see each line, eg when rowspan="2" i would like to see 2 tr,when rowspan="1" i would like to see  tr, when rowspan="34" i would like to see 34 tr.

Comment: you need to parse rowspan attribute and loop forward to to show them all.

Comment: Good attempt! But there is still a logical flaw in your jsfiddle-script: You only check the `<td>` that matches the search pattern for the `rowspan` attribute. So, for example, when searching for `256` you will _not_ get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick. I hope it is still helpful to someone:

```js
$("#search").focus().on("keyup", function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var trs=$("table tr:nth-child(n+2)");
  for (let i=0;i<trs.length;){
    let grp=$(trs.slice(i,i+=trs[i].children[0].rowSpan));
    $(grp).toggle( !!$('td:contains('+value+')', grp).length );
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>XY</th>
    <th>ZW</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">321</td>
    <td>242</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>513256</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>33131</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4131</td>
    <td>334132</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">51311</td>
    <td>54424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>54424</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5442</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>511</td>
    <td>544</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"s></input>
```

The action happens in these lines:

```
var trs=$("table tr:nth-child(n+2)");
```

The jQuery object `trs` holds all table records below the title line. In the loop
`for (let i=0;i<trs.length;){...}` these `<tr>`s will be grouped according to the content of the `rowspan` attribute of the first `<td>` in each record `trs[i]`:

```
let grp=$(trs.slice(i,i+=trs[i].children[0].rowSpan));
```

This newly created group is now `toggle()`-d (i. e. shown or hidden) on the basis of
 `!!$('td:contains('+value+')'` (--> this expression returns a boolean).

```
$(grp).toggle( !!$('td:contains('+value+')', grp).length );
```